# Rigify error even though the only bones missing or modified are the face bones

Tags: rigging

I'm really confused because the only bones I accidentally deleted before are the pelvis and heel bones, which I then restored to their exact original states. I'm not really sure what to try in this situation.

Here is the error I got:

RIGIFY ERROR: Bone 'thigh.L': Input to rig type must be a chain of at least 4 bones.

Incorrect armature for type 'limb_rigs'

Comment: Sounds as if you may have restored them but not linked them back into the armature correctly. Share you file so that someone can test it here. https://pasteall.org/blend/ and post the link to it into your question.

Answer (score 0):

In the Metarig Heel bone has to be child of the foot bone, in order to work.

When in doubt, go to edit mode and add a Rigify sample of the part you're working on, parent it and snap it into position or analyze how is it constructed.

Every chain of bones has a Rigify Type set on its first bone (you can read it in pose mode) and Rigify Types have a Parent/child relationship according on how the rig is structured.

[image]
[image]

Comment: I did that and analyzed how its constructed, but it all seems to be put together correctly. I did notice that the toe bones weren't parented to the foot bones but correcting that didn't fix the issue. I'm a bit new to rigging so did I miss something?

Comment: edit: the toe bones werent childs of the feet bones

Comment: Nevermind I just restarted the rig. Thanks anyways.